# in excel, how can I automatically change the content of a cell if it equals a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently working with a column of data (numbers) that corresponds to a set of values, and I was wondering how I could go about automatically replacing the data/numbers with the correct corresponding value? (have provided a picture of what I mean below) thanks for your help!

**Beginning Data**

[image]

**Final Result**

[image]

Comment: how automatic? Do you want a formula or vba solution? you could use the vlookup function in the adjacent column B if J and K are switched. and then paste the results over what is in A, or the index function. Or were you looking for a way to just change automatically when entering a number in A?

Comment: @datatoo Hello, I am just looking for a way to change automatically when entering a number in A

Comment: so anytime you enter a number in A it should find the appropriate value.

Comment: @datatoo yep exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worksheet change event you can do something like this.
It assumes the column you are doing the entry in is A and the layout of your lookups is in K&J as per your example. You can adjust the ranges as you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  'should check you are doing entry in column A first
If Target.Column = 1 Then
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Dim R1 As Range
 Dim R2 As Range
 Dim rngStart As Range
 Dim varFind As Variant
 Dim InRange As Boolean
   Set R1 = Range(Target.Address)
    Set R2 = Range("J:J")
      Set rngStart = Range("J1")

   If R2.Find(What:=Target, After:=rngStart, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) Is Nothing Then

     Application.EnableEvents = True
        Set R1 = Nothing
        Set R2 = Nothing

     Exit Sub
   Else
    varFind = R2.Find(What:=Target, After:=rngStart, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole _
    , SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Address

      Set varFind = Range(varFind)
        R1.Value = varFind.Offset(0, -1)
   Application.EnableEvents = True
      Set R1 = Nothing
      Set R2 = Nothing
      Set rngStart = Nothing
      Set varFind = Nothing
   End If
  Else
    Exit Sub
 End If
End Sub
```