# In Excel, how can I automatically change the data of a cell (VBA)?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I would like to automatically change the contents of cells when data is pasted into them. The data will be pasted into Column Q of a sheet on Excel. I need it to match it with data in Column A of another sheet, titled 'Users', and return the corresponding value from Column B of the same sheet. I presume it will require use of VBA, although I have very little understanding of VBA coding!

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain what you are trying to do, including what you've already tried, then ask how to accomplish it. By including the method of solution in your question limits answers to only VBA solutions. There might be a non VBA solution.

Comment: Look up `worksheet change event` and let us know where you get stuck

Comment: Do you mean that when you input certain value in column Q in _sheet1_, then Excel to "_look up_" that value in column A of _sheet2_ and return the value of  column B of _sheet 2_ to _sheet1_. But in which column in _sheet1_?

Comment: Please do not tell me that it should change the value in  column Q in _sheet1_. Then this becomes a cyclic connection. Excel will throw a warning - in this case

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. I've found a code for something which seems pretty much the same as I'm looking for in an answer to another question on this site: http://superuser.com/questions/541674/in-excel-how-can-i-automatically-change-the-content-of-a-cell-if-it-equals-a-ce

I'm struggling to work out how to adapt it to the cells I'm working with. I've changed my layout a little bit. So the cells I'm pasting data into are in Column Q. The cells I want to lookup are in Column Z of the same sheet, and I would like it to return the corresponding value from column AA.

Comment: Sorry, I am finding this hard to understand. You paste in value(s) into Col Q. What makes the value in Q correspond to Col Z? EG, if I paste "this" into Q1 and "that" into Q2, would it then look at the value of Z1 and Z2, copy those values directly into AA1 and AA2? If so, why does the paste matter? Or, does it only copy the values if the value in Q1 matches that in Z1, and likewise for Q2 and Z2?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do what you want. There is no way (that I know of) to detect only pastes.

The closest is to use

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

But, this means it will fire every time any change on the page is made.

So, as a work around, what you can do is paste into Col Q and then manually run a macro (which you can assign to a button if easier).

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatchThePairs()

'You can edit this top bit

'The name of column you are pasting into
Dim pastedCol As String
pastedCol = "Q" 'UPDATE ME IF NEEDED

'The name of the look up column
Dim lookupCol As String
lookupCol = "Z" 'UPDATE ME IF NEEDED

'The name of the look to show results
Dim resultCol As String
resultCol = "AA" 'UPDATE ME IF NEEDED

'Do you want to clear the results first ?
Dim clearResults As Boolean
clearResults = True 'CHANGE ME TO True OR False

'What is the row of the header (if you have one)
Dim rowHeader As Integer
rowHeader = 1 ' set to 0 if no header

'What is the name of the results column
Dim resultsColHeader As String
resultsColHeader = "ResultsCol" ' Change me to what ever

'what is the first row (do not include the headings)
Dim row As Integer
row = 2 'AS PER THE SCEEN SHOT, I STARTED ON ROW 2



' **** hopefully you won't need to edit anything below this

If clearResults Then
    Range(resultCol & ":" & resultCol).Cells.Clear

    If rowHeader > 0 Then
       Range(resultCol & rowHeader).Value = resultsColHeader
    End If


End If

Do While (Range(pastedCol & row).Value <> "")

    If Range(pastedCol & row).Value = Range(lookupCol & row).Value Then
        'yipee, a match
        Range(resultCol & row).Value = Range(lookupCol & row).Value
    End If
    row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]